# Change the size of the column in product detail page

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.2.4, category-description, uielement

I am using Magento 2.2.4. I need to **change the size of the column for product description** under the id="maincontent". I need to make it **70%** of the width and align **center**. I am writing a custom theme for these modifications extending from 'Luma' theme. How can be done this?

Comment: Provide the class name or id on which you want 70%?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I need it for the class

Comment: For maincontent?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Yes I need the whole content to be centered

Comment: For product details page only?

Comment: @SukumarGorai No, truly I need to make the whole website's pages in that way. Since I am newbie, I am trying some of the feature changes specifically in product detail page.

Comment: Try this one: #maincontent.page-main{width:50%;} it should work but you need to work on the inner items as they will break if you decrease the width of maincotent.

Comment: @SukumarGorai Can you tell where this file resides? Or else, in which directory should I create this CSS modification or complete CSS file to override the original one?

Comment: You can copy the less files from luma to your theme and update the changes you want. Or you can create your own css file and write your own css.